# Dynamically adjust Textfield width to Content

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way in Qooxdoo to automatically adjust the width of the `qx.ui.form.TextField` to fit its Content? 
It means if someone types in the Textfield it should grow and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520tt%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField()%253B%250Athis.getRoot().add(tt)%253B%250A%250A%250Att.addListener(%2522input%2522%252Cfunction(e)%257B%250A%2520%2520this.setWidth(parseInt(getTextWidth(e.getData()%252C%2520%252212px%2520Verdana%2522))%252B10)%253B%250A%257D%252Ctt)%253B%250A%250Afunction%2520getTextWidth(text%252C%2520font)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520canvas%2520%253D%2520getTextWidth.canvas%2520%257C%257C%2520(getTextWidth.canvas%2520%253D%2520document.createElement(%2522canvas%2522))%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520context%2520%253D%2520canvas.getContext(%25222d%2522)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520context.font%2520%253D%2520font%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520metrics%2520%253D%2520context.measureText(text)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520metrics.width%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) in the Qooxdoo playground that listen to input's updates, use the canvas to calculate the text's length and adjust the `textfield`'s width.

```js
var tt = new qx.ui.form.TextField();
this.getRoot().add(tt);


tt.addListener("input",function(e){
  this.setWidth(parseInt(getTextWidth(e.getData(), "12px Verdana"))+10);
},tt);

function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
}
```